# C# key not valid for use in specified state in signing pdf

Tags: c#, itext

I have a digital certificate with which I want to sign PDF files digitally, and for that reason, I'm developing a software in C# ... I am using iTextSharp and BouncyCastle API as well as Core Libraries of .NET...

I have a certificate object of x509Certificate2 named x509 with which I need to find out a Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair object like this

```
Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair cert = DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(x509.PrivateKey);
```

Then I add it to the following line provided by iTextSharp

```
PrivateKeySignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(cert.Private,DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);
```

but the previous line containing 'GetKeyPair' receives an exception telling that key is not valid for use in specified state.

Can not figure out the reason behind this.

Comment: You can check http://bo.lt/7x2j3 or let us see detail of your code

Comment: this is not the answer I'm looking for

Comment: Please clarify "I have a digital certificate with which I want to sign PDF files digitally." Not all digital certificates are valid to sign a document. Maybe the error is correct. To use an analogy: if you try to start your car using the key to your house, you'll also run into trouble. I recognize your code from the examples that are published with the documentation I wrote http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures All these examples were successfully tested in Java and C# using valid keys.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is that when the certificate was loaded into the certificate store that the allow export option was checked.  This is not the only reason that would cause this failure but it is a reason.